# "on_raw_reaction_add" working and "and on_raw_reaction_remove" not working why?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this auto assign role on reaction code and on_reaction_add is working just fine but the on_reaction_add_remove is giving me an error why?

**CODE**

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    msgID = 754487460142121070  
    user = payload.user_id
    member = payload.member

    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot1.guilds)
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="penis")

    if payload is not None:
        if payload.message_id == msgID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == "<:bbc:639345897922101248>":
                await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):

    msgID = 754487460142121070  
    user = payload.user_id
    member = payload.member

    guild_id = payload.guild_id
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, member.guilds)
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="penis")

    if payload is not None:
        if payload.message_id == msgID:
            if str(payload.emoji) == "<:bbc:639345897922101248>":
                await member.add_removes(role)
```

**error raw_reaction_remove**

> ```
> Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py",
> ```
>
> line 312, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/CIP/Documents/GitHub/billionaireboysclub/lojinha.py", line
> 150, in on_raw_reaction_remove
> guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, member.guilds)
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guilds'

Comment: Link provided should help with the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66638693/15363060

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting a member object from the [payload](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), so you are getting a `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guilds'` on `member.guilds`

However instead of this:

```
guild_id = payload.guild_id
guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, member.guilds)
```

I would recommend:

```
guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
```

this might not fix your member problem but it is cleaner than trying to pull a guild object out of a members guilds.

also you have a typo: `await member.add_removes(role)`, you probably meant `remove_roles`

EDIT:

You may want to filter out any non guild reactions by adding:

```
if not payload.guild_id:
    return
```

at the very top of your `on_raw_reaction_add` and `on_raw_reaction_remove`