# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles' Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Keep getting an error for the reaction_remove, just copy-pasted my whole code(minus the client id) cause it might help, I have no idea what's wrong as the first half works perfectly fine. [image: Error in console]

Also, trying to add
"if member is not None:
await member.remove_roles(role)
else:
Print(error)"
at the very end and itgave me errors every time I tried removing roles, just in case it helps.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event 
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    
    if message_id == 806406876593127464:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "049":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-049')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "0492":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-049-2')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "096":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-096')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "106":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-106')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "173":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-173')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "682":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-682')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "939":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-939')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "999":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-999')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "Chaos":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'Chaos Insurgency')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "DClass":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'D-Class')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "MTF":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'MTF')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "Scientist":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'Scientist')

        member = payload.member
        await member.add_roles(role)

@client.event 
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    message_id = payload.message_id
    
    if message_id == 806406876593127464:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "049":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-049')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "0492":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-049-2')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "096":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-096')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "106":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-106')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "173":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-173')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "682":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-682')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "939":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-939')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "999":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'SCP-999')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "Chaos":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'Chaos Insurgency')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "DClass":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'D-Class')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "MTF":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'MTF')
        elif payload.emoji.name == "Scientist":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = 'Scientist')

        member = payload.member
        await member.remove_roles(role)
client.run()
```

It was able to give me a role after adding a reaction, but has not been able to remove the role after removing that reaction [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxRdX.jpg)

Comment: Is it getting a role object? Try print(role) above your error line

Comment: Just added a picture of the console with both print(role) and print(member) just before the member.add/remove_roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer is one part of the solution to make this code work so implement the provided answer. I found out in another issue that in the documentation `payload.member` is only available if the `event_type` is `REACTION_ADD` so i fixed it by adding:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

After you have added this, change the

```
member = payload.member
```

to

```
member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
```

That is what worked for me let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you try printing the `payload.member` the output will be `None`  - it's because you didn't enable `intents.members`. To enable them:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developer/applications)

[How to enable privileged intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents)

Comment: I added this in and added it to the dev portal, but it didn’t change anything at all

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is still an active problem, but I had the same problem and solved it right now after some time and wanted to share with you how I have done this.

I hope i could help other peoble with this.

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

↑ Add this at the top of your code right under imports



@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = payload.member
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='regeln')
    channel_id = channel.id
    message_id = 874741218523873370

    if message_id == payload.message_id:
        if payload.channel_id == channel_id:
            if emoji == '1️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News1')
            if emoji == '2️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News2')
            if emoji == '3️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News3')
            if emoji == '4️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News4')
        await member.add_roles(role)



@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name='regeln')
    channel_id = channel.id
    message_id = 874741218523873370

    if message_id == payload.message_id:
        if payload.channel_id == channel_id:
            if emoji == '1️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News1')
            if emoji == '2️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News2')
            if emoji == '3️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News3')
            if emoji == '4️⃣':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='News4')
        await member.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: Also make sure to enable the intents in the discord developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

[`payload.member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.member) will always be `None` when the event is `on_raw_reaction_remove`. As such, you will have to use `guild.get_member()` and the payload's `user_id` to obtain the member from cache, which also requires having the *members intent* enabled.